# iPhone sdk Tool Tip

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitouch

Can i show a Tool tip like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Also, I want to show this tool tip when that area is pressed and HOLD. Is there a handler for this gesture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in `didSelectRowAtIndex` method of `TableViewController` delegate method.

Look [here](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover). It is best implementation to have Popover controllers in iPhone. Download run and integrate into your code and change according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @jennis said, there is indeed a way to capture long hold gestures you could use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

like this

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longHold)];

[cell addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

and longHold method

```
- (void) longHold
{
     //Cell has recieved gesture
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It works, I agree with Omar Abdelhafith

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ //gesture declared in .h file
    gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longHold)];
    [your view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

-(void)longHlod
{
//do whatever you want
}
```